# Servicio con GPS no se que context poner

Tags: android, android-studio, gps, timer, android-service

Acabo de crear un servicio:
public class TimerGPS extends Service {

que me genera un timer

```
public int onStartCommand(Intent intencion, int flags, int idArranque) {
        oGPSTimer = new Timer();
        oGPSTimer.schedule(new TimerGPS.GPSTarea(),5,GPSIntervalo);
        return START_NOT_STICKY;
```

el cual llama a este:

```
 private void fn_getlocation(){
        locationManager = (LocationManager)getApplicationContext().getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
        isGPSEnable = locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
        isNetworkEnable = locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);

        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getApplicationContext(), Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getApplicationContext(), Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        }

        if (!isGPSEnable && !isNetworkEnable){

        }else {

            if (isNetworkEnable){
                location = null;
                locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER,1000,0, this);
                //getApplicationContext()
                //getBaseContext()
                //context
                //getContext().getApplicationContext()
                //getActivity()
```

Mi problema esta que no resuelve el método (eso me dice) en esta linea

```
locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER,1000,0, this);
```

puse todas estas opciones  `getApplicationContext()`, también
`getBaseContext()`, `context`, `getContext().getApplicationContext()`,`getActivity()`

y no funciona.

Comment: No entiendo la pregunta, quieres llamar al `onStartCommand` desde `fn_getlocation`?

Comment: se encuentra en otra clase fn_getlocation() o dentro de TimerGPS  ? @OsirisStto

Comment: En un instante pegaré todo el codigo. No me resuelve en esta linea: locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER,1000,0,this). En lugar de this tengo que poner otro contexto y no se cual

Comment: @Bicho y @ Jorgesys gracias... este es el codigo completo... no puedo pegarlo aca asi que lo subi en este link https://www.stempelatto.com.ar/agenda/index.html

Comment: Ok ya veo , el método se encuentra en la misma clase del servicio , agregue una respuesta @OsirisStto saludos

Answer (score 1):

En un servicio el contexto es el mismo servicio, en este caso puedes usar `TimerGPS.this` como contexto:

```
locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER,1000,0, TimerGPS.this);
```

Comment: Ups.. no funciona... me dice:
 method LocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(String,long,float,LocationListener) is not applicable
      (argument mismatch; TimerGPS cannot be converted to LocationListener)
    method LocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(String,long,float,PendingIntent) is not applicable
      (argument mismatch; TimerGPS cannot be converted to PendingIntent)
    method LocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(long,float,Criteria,PendingIntent) is not applicable
      (argument mismatch; String cannot be converted to long)

Comment: Notarás @Jorgesys , que soy nuevo.
Pase este problema ya que lo que necesitaba era un listener. Lo agregé ( private final LocationListener locationListenerGPS = new LocationListener() {
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) { )
Ahora me para la app y dice:  java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()
        at android.os.Handler.<init>(Handler.java:200)

Comment: Descubrí que esta es la linea que me genera el error:
locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 1000, 0, locationListenerGPS);

El error es:
Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()
        at android.os.Handler.<init>(Handler.java:200)
        at android.os.Handler.<init>(Handler.java:114)
        at android.location.LocationManager$ListenerTransport$1.<init